# Special relativity and missing factors of $c$

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, units, absolute-units

I am doing problems in a textbook called 'Introduction to Classical Mechanics' by David Morin. In one of the questions it says the following:

> In the lab frame, two particles move with speed $v$ along the path shown [image]
>
> The angle between the trajectories is $2\theta$. What is the speed of
>   one particle, as viewed by the other?

I know how to do this question but what has confused me in the answers he has left out all of the c's. Here is his method

> Consider the frame S' that travels along the point P midway between the particles. S' moves at speed $v cos\theta$, so the $\gamma$ factor relating it to the lab frame is: $$\gamma =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2cos^2\theta}}$$

From what I have learned there should be a $v^2/c^2$ instead of just $v^2$. He has repeated a similar method 4 times in the book (from what I can see) all without the $c^2$, which makes me think that I have got something wrong thinking their should be a c. Please explain thanks.

He then goes onto use the velocity addition formula like this:

> $$V=\frac{2u'_y}{1+u^{'2}_{y}}$$

Comment: People sometimes use natural units (in which c=1). Maybe check foreword if it says something?

Comment: @mihapriimek have just added some more information, which I think may rule this out??

Comment: As @miha priimek suggests, it's standard to use units such that c=1 and then to omit c from all subsequent equations/formulae.

Comment: Kyle has covered what is happening here just fine, but let me note that learning how to put the c's back in is a useful skill, and it works by paying careful attention to the dimensionality of each quantity. Masses get two c's and momenta and times get 1 if you want to leave energy and distances without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of the chapter, the author does use $c$ for the [Lorentz transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) (cf., Equation (13.1)). 
\begin{align}
A_0&=\gamma(A_0'+(v/c)A_1') \\
A_1&=\gamma(A_1'+(v/c)A_0') \\
A_2&=A_2'\\
A_3&=A_3'
\end{align}

Shortly after Equation (13.1), the author lists several enumerated remarks. In particular is #4:

> 4. Lest we get tired of writing the $c$'s over and over, we'll work in units where $c=1$ from now on.

And then he re-writes the Lorentz transformations in the new units in Equation (13.2),
\begin{align}
A_0&=\gamma(A_0'+vA_1') \\
A_1&=\gamma(A_1'+vA_0') \\
A_2&=A_2'\\
A_3&=A_3'
\end{align}

Comment: This is simply an excuses but I set my self the challenge of doing all the 1 star questions in this book and hence have not read the chapters in any depth. In all the questions before this he did not use these units and/or it was not relevant. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem! Hopefully it's a lesson to read the chapter before diving into the problems ;)

Comment: I am severely dyslexia so I find doing the problems directs me to the relevant bits of the chapters without having to read large pieces of text (again another excuse)